# add new vertex attributes in igraph

Tags: r, igraph

how can I add vertex attributes while keeping the existing ones?

```
g <- make_ring(5) %>% set_vertex_attr("label", value = LETTERS[1:5])
label2 <- as.data.frame(c("Aa", "Bb", "Cc", "Dd", "Ee"))
rownames(label2) <- 1:5
colnames(label2) <- "label2"

vertex_attr(g) <- label2
g
V(g)$label2
V(g)$label
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I solved. It was very simple, I just added the object as an attribute:

```
g <- make_ring (5)%>% set_vertex_attr ("label", value = LETTERS [1: 5])
label2 <- c ("Aa", "Bb", "Cc", "Dd", "Ee")
label2
V (g) $ label2 <- label2
g
```

As against, you can only one attribute at a time.